# SQL-syntax (might be SQL lite related)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, syntax

Following does 3 table's join:

1. On the Device Number  - Always a number so just joins on 2 columns
2. On the Slot number - 1st case "Logs.Slot"  is number , 2nd "slotlist2" is a comma separated list.
3. On the Slot - Def_Instances.slot is like Logs.Slot (meaning its a number and is realted to Logs.Slot) but has the value of  Offset +1 was substracted from it.

Now I want to get syntax right for the following when using SQL lite

```
select  Logs.*, Def_Instances.*, (Def_Instances.slot + Def_Instances.Offset + 1) as A from Def_Instances
inner join Logs ON Logs.Column1 = Def_Instances.DeviceNumber 
and (', ' || RTRIM(Def_Instances.slotlist2) || ',') LIKE '%, '|| Logs.Slot ||',%' 
and (', ' || RTRIM(Def_Instances.A) || ',') LIKE '%, '|| Logs.Slot ||',%'
```

Well that one tells me htere is an error.

When I was playing around. It either does not recognieses + sign or a Column A or as far as i can remember there was one more error I recived earlier.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use column alias from the `select` clause in the `where` clause.  Don't forget, SQL first removes rows (runs the `where` clause) before projecting output (running the `select` clause).

You'll have to put the expression in the `where` clause.  And probably do some type conversion since it appears to be numeric at one point, then you start treating it like a string.